# How to extract the image files from wireshark logs

Tags: wireshark

I have sent some print jobs to my `network printer` and capture the `Wireshark` log.
How can i extract the `test data` (image files) from the logs which i sent to the printer.

here is the process I follow to capture the logs

```
1) ip.addr === < ip >

2) once got the filter tried to export the logs
```

I am exporting the logs to text file i am getting huge files but my test data was not there.

Any help will be grateful

Comment: reference to [this link](http://packetlife.net/blog/2009/jul/13/quick-packet-capture-data-extraction/) might help you.